# Find counts between multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I thought this was a simple pivot, but seem to have mixed things up.

Given the following data:

```
np.random.seed(2)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (5, 3)), columns=list("abc"))
```

which looks as:

```
   a  b  c
0  0  1  1
1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  1  0  1
4  1  1  1
```

I expect to create a table where the rows and columns are `a b c`, and the values are the counts.

The expected output is the following:

```
  | a   b   c
--|-----------
a | 2   1   2   
  |
b | 1   3   2
  |
c | 2   2   4
```

Comment: Count of what?  How does [b,c] = 2  and [a,c] = 1?

Comment: @JeffUK of the values in `b` which are `1`, two of those are `1` within `c`.

Comment: @JeffUK correct , sorry

Comment: @JeffUK Yes, I guess it should be `2`. jezrael has answered that nicely.